# XML clean up using PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, tags, file-io

I have dirty .out file which I'm converting to xml.
I am cleaning it using php and then converting. I have this problem. All URLs are encoded and i need it to be in normal decoded format.

```
<article type="video" enterID="33">
<addedDate>2010-12-02 16:40:26</addedDate>
<thumbnail>http://eyops.com/sdfgsefgefsoio81f8b35.jpg</thumbnail>
<asset href="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBu927_ul_X0" addedDate="2010-12-02 16:40:23">
<duration>1500</duration>
</asset>
</article>
```

how do i get the href from  tag, decode it and then write the output to the xml file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a node attribute from XML using PHPs DOM parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993302/how-to-extract-a-node-attribute-from-xml-using-phps-dom-parser/3995983#3995983)

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/urldecode

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving and reading an XML file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361876/saving-and-reading-a-xml-file-getting-from-the-other-url/3361906#3361906)

Answer (score 0):

Parse your xml with dom, getAttribute('href') for specific nodes, create the new link decoding the current link, and set the attribute with the new link.

After that, save your edits.

http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattribute.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/met_element_setattribute.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use urldecode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php to convert. How you go about extracting and replacing in the output depends on what tools your are using for that.